# BATCH: Delete parts of filename using substring not working

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I have several .csv files in one folder. They are saved automatically but with spaces and execution date and time (in seconds) with amount of containing lines.
So far I was not able to run my powershell script with files containing spaces. So I tried to rename filenames using batch. so far nothing is working fine. Either in cmd-line or with a batch file.
Trying to loop in folder to find .csv is working but defining a string and then substring parts of the file not.

```
for %%i in ('dir *.csv /b /s') do set string = %%~ni
set substr=!string:~20,25!
echo !substr!
```

I tried first to use % instead of ! but didn't worked as well. Tried to use pipes for the loop as well, didn't worked.
So far my output is just

```
!string:~20,25!
```

My output has to be just the "real" filename of the report without anything else before or after it.
For example, do with that path and filename

```
C:\Users\Username\CSV_Files\Reportoutput Report_2017 2018-01-09T07_10_33.1924R.csv
```

this

```
C:\Users\Username\CSV_Files\Report_2017.csv
```

When I'm able to extract just the filename without any spaces or leading chars like "Reportoutput" (which is always the same) or starting time of report or containing lines in the report I could use that string and combine it with the path where files are saved.

Any ideas? Why is my "substring" not working at all? Do I miss some action? Some code?

I'm using windows.

Comment: You have to add this line to your code before using `!`: `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion`

Comment: `set string = %%~ni` sets a variable `%string %`, and it adds a leading space to the value. Remove the spaces from both sides of `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the file name structure you've presented and looping in one folder, *(the current directory)*, as stated *and used in your example code*:

```bat
@Echo Off
For %%A In ("* * *.csv"
) Do For /F "Tokens=2" %%B In ("%%~nA") Do Ren "%%~A" "%%B%%~xA"
```

If you wanted to check inside subfolders of the currect directory then change it to this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /R %%A In ("* * *.csv"
) Do For /F "Tokens=2" %%B In ("%%~nA") Do Ren "%%~A" "%%B%%~xA"
```

…and if you want to specify the base directory name then you can do so like the following two examples which use `%UserProfile%` for demonstration purposes, *(change as appropriate)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /R "%UserProfile%" %%A In ("* * *.csv"
) Do For /F "Tokens=2" %%B In ("%%~nA") Do Ren "%%~A" "%%B%%~xA"
```

and:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "%UserProfile%" 2>Nul||Exit /B
For /R %%A In ("* * *.csv"
) Do For /F "Tokens=2" %%B In ("%%~nA") Do Ren "%%~A" "%%B%%~xA"
```

*Instead of splitting the names using character numbers, this simply takes the second token of the file name string delimited by spaces and adds the original file extension to it in a rename command.*

Comment: Tihs is totally working fine! Thanks a lot. But can you explain me? I understand what "Tokens" is doing but have no idea about the letters "A" or "B".

Comment: Those are effectively placeholders for the output of the content between the parentheses. So if we look at the examples, the first loop holds each file name as `%%A`, I want the filename without extension only, which based on the info under `For /?` is equivalent to `%%~nA`. I want to split `%%~nA` using a default delimiter, _(spaces and tabs are default)_, and retain only the second token, _(the string after the first delimiter)_. I then rename the full file name, `%%A` to the second token, `%%B`, and append the file extension, which based on the info under `For /?` is equivalent to `%%~xA`.